# How URL query parameters are generated?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, ajax

[image]

How are the parameters after node?_=xxxxxx are being generated?

### How can I capture these if using a Python script to get the URL?

edit:
Apologies for not enough info. My first novice post.

I am trying to get the nodes dictionary using Python from Eve-NG API.

Eve-NG API Docs Ref: 
https://www.eve-ng.net/index.php/documentation/howtos/how-to-eve-ng-api/

```
curl -s -c /tmp/cookie -b /tmp/cookie
-X GET -H 'Content-type: application/json'
http://127.0.0.1/api/labs/User1/Lab%201.unl/nodes
```

with above I get a dictionary with nodes data, all the info is correct except url key value "url":"/html5/#/client/MzI3OTIAYwBteXNxbA==?token=AE...000"

expected value is - "url": "telnet://127.0.0.1:32769" as show in eve-ng docs.

From Chrome Developer Tools if I open - http://127.0.0.1/api/labs/User1/Lab%201.unl/nodes?158489xxxx in a tab, I can see the correct "url": "telnet://127.0.0.1:32769" key/value pair.

you can see in the screenshot the GET request has query parameters node?_=xxxxxxx 
how can find out how these numbers/timestamps/encoded values are being generated?
or how can I modify Python script to capture these can make the correct GET request?

Hope this explains the issue.

Thanks

Comment: There's not really enough context to understand the problem here, but looking at the values I'd guess they're timestamps in milliseconds.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Do you want to know how they're generated or how to capture them in php?  Does it matter?  This is normally done just to ensure the server/proxy/browser doesn't cache the file.

Comment: Ok .. thanks for pointers .. these are indeed timestamps in ms .. I have converted current time in ms int and appended to the get url .. still didn't get the correct url key/value pair.

Comment: modified url = 'http://192.168.106.133/api/labs/Dev.unl/nodes?_={}'.format(int(time_stamp)) still no luck with correct url key/value in the dict return. How is it showing correctly in browser but showing differently with get request? Any ideas?

Comment: EVE-NG has an option to select native or html5 console. 
With Native console, the device connection are opened with 3rd part apps like Putty
with html5 console, connections open in a browser tab. 
If I login to the html5 console I see similar key/value pair as with api get request. 
So api get request is going to html5 console and in the browser, telnet connections are shown in the native console.

Comment: Don't know how to select the native console in python script I was hoping the post request from a browser may answer but when i login the is no POST from the browser. I guess its happening in JS .. I have no idea about.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<select name="html5" class="form-control" ng-init="html5='-1'" placeholder="html5" ng-model="html5">
    <option value="-1" selected="">Native console</option>
    <option value="1">Html5 console</option>
</select>
  </div>
```